# Comparator operator in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, yang-mills, unitarity

In Peskin and Shroeder, for a local $U(1)$ transformation, the comparator operator is expanded as:
\begin{equation}
U(x+\epsilon n, x) = 1 -ie\epsilon n^{\mu}A_{\mu} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)
\tag{15.5}
\end{equation}
for $\epsilon\rightarrow0$. I am not sure how one arrives at this expression, apart from "feeling" that it should depend on the distance $\epsilon n^{\mu}$, thus needing some other vector quantity.

Later, when talking about $SU(2)$, they expand $U$ as:
\begin{equation}
U(x+\epsilon n,x) = 1 + ig\epsilon n^{\mu}A^i_{\mu}\frac{\sigma^i}{2}+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2).
\tag{15.23}
\end{equation}
Where did this sign change come from?
The authors also say that $U$ can be consistently restricted to be a unitary matrix and because of that, can be expanded as above. How do we know it is possible? This question was already asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110769/why-is-the-yang-mills-comparator-unitary), but the only answer is cyclical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A concept you're going to want to look in to is [parallel transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport). Long story short - you have some underlying manifold (your space) that you want to move locally defined quantities around in, and that movement process has to be continuous/smooth, and preserve inner products. Everything else follows from those requirements and how the vector space being transported relates to the manifold and its symmetries: producing notions of covariant derivatives, expansion at linear order being sufficient to build the transformations up from infinitesimal steps, etc.